# Google's Index status falling down without any site changes

Tags: google-index

I've a site but it wasn't touched since Sept 2013(not even comments). But in the curve I can see that Google's index has fallen down.

**What could be the reason?**

Though the site's traffic halted completely after Jan 2014.

UPDATE: I've never purchased any links nor even built backlinks for this site. I simply left it partially unfinished. Absolutely no spam. It is about courses in colleges/universities.

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information to get a specific answer for your specific site issue...URL? Backlink History (buying links etc, Content scraping or anything that Google may take a dim-view on - an WebmasterTools messages?)

Comment: Put on hold! Off topic? I've asked a basic Webmasters question.

Comment: Your question is simply too specific to your situation, and too vague in detail to supply anything other than a vague answer (like my own).

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions on why Google's indexation status falling down:

Your site has not been updated frequently is a main point.

- A Site should get updated in contents during each Indexing by Google robots. Which will keeps your site awake & up to date. Without any update, your site will not be Crawled and visible at the top of the search engine for the enduser. Make sure the contents that you are going to update is unique and which can pass the compare algorithm by Google.
- I agree with Mike Hudson on "Crawl budget lessened since Googlebot hasn't detected any new changes, so no longer crawls or indexes as deep or as frequently."

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer this definitively, but here are some suggested possibilities why Google's indexation status might decline:

- Indexing algorithm update that affects the way Google
  discovers/indexes your site.
- Crawl budget lessened since Googlebot hasn't detected any new changes, so no longer crawls or indexes as deep or as frequently.
- Loss or reduction in your back-links which may affect your crawl budget.